# Console game - How to return "var"

Tags: c#, console

I need help with my console game.
I am working on the "arena" with gladiators.
In the start of the game, u will choose your class (war, hunter, etc.) (every class have own class.cs)
But in the code, I have a method for showing "menu" and on this menu, u are choosing your class, so I need to return this specific class.cs. If you know what I mean.
So I want to ask how should I do that.

```
 public static "something" Menu(int cislo)
    {
        bool starthry = false;
            switch (cislo)
            {
                case 1:
                   
                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int vyber))
                    {
                        string jmeno = Console.ReadLine();
                        switch (vyber)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Bojovnik bojovnik = new Bojovnik(jmeno);
                                break;
                            /*case 2:
                                Lukostrelec lukostrelec = new Lukostrelec(jmeno);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Assassin assassin = new Assassin(jmeno);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Mag mag = new Mag(jmeno);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                Nekromant nekromant = new Nekromant(jmeno);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                Druid druid = new Druid(jmeno);
                                break;*/
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                        starthry = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"../../Postava.dat", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                    sw.Write(postava.Info());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (Console.ReadLine() == "Y")
                    {
                        string postavy = @"C:\Users\Dominik\source\repos\Pokus_o_hru_LOL\Pokus_o_hru_LOL\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Postavy.docx";
                        Process proces = new Process();
                        proces.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                        {
                            UseShellExecute = true,
                            FileName = postavy
                        };
                        proces.Start();
                        proces.WaitForExit();
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            //here i need to return my character
        }
```

Comment: You can't return `var` because `var` is syntatic sugar. When `var a = "hello";` is compiled, `var` becomes its actual type (i.e. `string`). [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQG4CGATovYgLyIBEAFgKYA2/APacA3NRo4AlgDNEpAC6MArr3ITJWGJJ0t2egNRcAhGI00AvhqswLQA===).

Comment: You will have to declare the method as returning a type that is common among all the possible return values, either an interface, base class, or even `object` if nothing else fits.

Comment: You mean I will have to do the method "menu" for each possible class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you should use interfaces. make an IClass, have all classes extend it and return an IClass. You can not make a method return a [var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) type because it is syntactic sugar.

Comment: Can I ask what is IClass? And how do you mean have all classes extend ?

Comment: @DominikKolouch Read up on interfaces https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_interface.asp

Comment: So if I am right, you mean I should do classes (warrior, mage...) like an interface class and 1 class "character"?

Comment: Do you have discord? If so it would be way easier to explain it to you there

Comment: Yeah, I have discord

Comment: Omni#6066 @DominikKolouch